# Using rules of inference with quantified statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Use rules of inference to show that

(a) $ ∀x (R(x) → (S(x) ∨ Q(x))$

$∃x (¬S(x))$

---

$  ∃x (R(x) → Q(x) )$

I'm kinda lost at what to do... I can start but don't know what to do afterwards

1) $R(a) → (S(a) ∨ Q(a) ) $ Universal Inst.

Comment: I don't believe that you can go from statement (1) to statement (2). For example: "If $a$ is real then either $a\geq 0$ or $a<0$" is true, but you can't conclude "If $a$ is real then $a<0$".

Comment: hmm good point, I got confuse with the simplification where the logical operator is AND and not OR. Makes me stuck even more! haha

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Begin by using your *second* premise: $\exists x (\tilde{} S(x))$ to conclude $\tilde{} S(a)$. Next, *assume* $R(a)$.  Now see what you can get!

Comment: I thought I couldn't use the same constant , a in this case, because one is existential and the other is universal. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: No, I'm saying start over from the very beginning. Your first move should be to use Existential Elimination (or whatever it's called) to move from $\exists x (\tilde{} S(x))$ to $\tilde{} S(a)$. Basically, what you're doing is "giving a name" to the object that doesn't have property $S$. In other words, our premise is that there is an object $x$ that doesn't have property $S$;  the Existential Elimination rule allows us to "call that object $a$". http://www.philosophy-index.com/logic/forms/existential-elimination.php

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I didn't asked right. I meant that because we gave a name to the existential variable ( a constant), I thought you couldn't do the same with the universal one. Also , how did you assume R(a) I mean you can use Universal Instatiation on the first premise, but you still get a conditional statement, no?

Comment: Well, you can *assume* anything you want, at any time. So you are allowed to assume $R(a)$ if you like, though you have to keep track of it as one of your assumptions (and you'll want to discharge this assumption later). But you can assume it for now, and see what you get. (In words, you're saying, "There's an object that doesn't have property $S$; let's call this object $a$. Now let's suppose that $a$ has the property $R$....")

Comment: I think I got it... It would give something like this : assume $R(a)$ and then get $R(a) → (S(a)∨Q(a)) $ and you can use modus poens getting $(S(a)∨Q(a))$ and then you can use disjunctive syll. with your initial $~S(x)$ to then get Q(a). and I'm stuck again!

Comment: Right, from $(S(a) \vee Q(a))$ and $\tilde{} S(a)$ you conclude $Q(a)$. Now, what was your assumption? Oh yeah, it was $R(a)$. Thus we've proven $R(a) \to Q(a)$, using only the given premises! One more step and you're done.